# Azure cloud service emulator - avoid restarting on breakpoint

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-emulator

When running an Azure cloud service instance locally in the emulator, if I spend too long while the code execution is paused (e.g. hit a breakpoint), the service will print 'unresponsive' error messages and will restart.

This is expected behaviour "at large", but is there a way to stop this from happening when running in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

> This is expected behaviour "at large", but is there a way to stop this from happening when running in the emulator?

Based on my test , if I stop at breakpoints for longer than a few minutes, which will make role state become unresponsive and role stop. We should avoid long stops at breakpoints.

[image]

I do not find a way to set/configure the Compute Emulator to prevent this behaviour from happening. You could give a feedback on [this site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role) for this issue.